# Explaining the positive and negative regions of the output waveform in a circuit involving a Zener diode

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator, zener

I am trying to find the explanation for the output waveform at Vo of the circuit below:
[image]

The output voltage is as follows:

[image]

Perhaps the explanation why the form is as such during the + cycle is because only approximately 7.5 volts is available after the current went across R2, and the Zener diode needs 5 volts to activate. Hence, only about +2.5 volts appeared on the positive region of the output waveform.

I am quite unsure for justifying the appearance of the negative region. I think the current went through the R3 first. The output voltage, thus, decreased to more or less -5 volts. Am I correct?

Comment: Is the 10.0 volts the peak voltage or the RMS voltage of the source. It's important to know.

Comment: @Andy aka - From the picture related to the waveform, it should be clear that the 10.0 V value is referred to the peak voltage...if it were the RMS voltage, the output peaks should have been much lower (as absolute values) than those indicated there!

Comment: @barrow you have much to learn.

Comment: @Andy aka - OK. So, please, could you elaborate your ideas? I'm ready to catch your teachings, if you light up the way.

Comment: If a voltage is stated as being 10 volts (with nothing else to guide you) then you should not assume it's peak voltage. The default engineering values are RMS. And, on this site, it's best always to get clarification first. And, if the op doesn't reply, then it's just not worth the effort to answer the question. That is what I know.

Comment: @Andy aka, @ Mohammad - There was no need to leave an answer, since it was already fully given by Mohammad below, being concise and clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During (+) cycle the Zener diode is reverse biased (Vz = 5). The other 5 V will be divided on the two resistors so the voltage across R3 is around 2.5 V.

During the (-) cycle the Zener diode is forward biased (Vf = 0.3 ~ 0.7). Assuming Vf = 0.6 V so -9.4 V will be divided on the resistors, thus the voltage across R3 will be around -4.7 V.